# R - function cgarchspec working well alone but not in apply function

Tags: r, function, apply

I want to run an apply function that is using different multivariate GARCH models with more and more data. To run the GARCH model, I need to run the `cgarchspec` function determining the number of variables I will fit afterwards. For some reason, the following `apply` function doesn't work

```
library(rmgarch)
func.garch.i <- function(x) {
cgarch11spec.loop <- cgarchspec(uspec =multispec(replicate(x,garch11.spec)), VAR = TRUE, robust = FALSE, lag = 1, lag.max = NULL,
                              lag.criterion = c("AIC", "HQ", "SC", "FPE"), external.regressors = NULL,
                              robust.control = list(gamma = 0.25, delta = 0.01, nc = 10, ns = 500),
                              dccOrder = c(1, 1), asymmetric = FALSE,
                              distribution.model = list(copula = c("mvnorm"),
                                                        method = c("Kendall"), time.varying = TRUE,
                                                        transformation = c("parametric")),
                              start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list())
}
nb <- seq(2,3)
apply(nb, func.garch.i(x))
```

Argument `garch11.spec` being defined as followed:

```
garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)),
                        variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1),
                                              model = "sGARCH"),
                        distribution.model = "norm")
```

But if I try to run `func.garch.i(2)` for example, it works well... Why is the function not working in the `apply` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have the same issue, I finally found the solution. The function `multispec` has to be isolated and computed before:

```
func.garch.i <- function(x) {
uspec <- multispec(replicate(x,garch11.spec))
cgarch11spec.loop <- cgarchspec(uspec, VAR = TRUE, robust = FALSE, lag = 1, lag.max = NULL,
                              lag.criterion = c("AIC", "HQ", "SC", "FPE"), external.regressors = NULL,
                              robust.control = list(gamma = 0.25, delta = 0.01, nc = 10, ns = 500),
                              dccOrder = c(1, 1), asymmetric = FALSE,
                              distribution.model = list(copula = c("mvnorm"),
                                                        method = c("Kendall"), time.varying = TRUE,
                                                        transformation = c("parametric")),
                              start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list())
}
```